# how to convert activity to fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-viewpager, slide

can anyone convert this activity to fragment . i am trying to create app with 3 activity with viewpager to slide between . i have already created all activity but not able to convert them to fragment and without fragment i cannot use viewpager

```
enter code here
```

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var site=""
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    imageButton110.getBackground().setAlpha(120);
}

fun instagram(view: View)
{
    site="https://www.instagram.com"
    val intent=Intent( this,web::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(key,site)
    startActivity(intent)

}
fun facebook(view: View)
{
    site="https://www.facebook.com"
    val intent=Intent( this,web::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(key,site)
    startActivity(intent)

}
fun youtube(view: View)
{
    site="https://www.youtube.com"
    val intent=Intent( this,web::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(key,site)
    startActivity(intent)

}
fun twitter(view: View)
{
    site="https://www.twitter.com"
    val intent=Intent( this,web::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(key,site)
    startActivity(intent)

}``
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `onClick` attributes in XML. Those don't work in anything but an Activity - you would need to override `onViewCreated()` in your Fragment and manually set an `OnClickListener` for each Button, rather than rely on the `onClick` attribute in XML.

Comment: but when i am using onclick listener , it is giving error  - Attempt to invoke virtual method setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference